# Настройка .htaccess и перенаправление на свои веб-страницы

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

*Всем доброго времени суток.*

У меня есть готовые странички ошибок в папке ***errors***, на которые должен осуществляться переход согласно файлу `.htaccess`. Но переходит на стандартные страницы хостинга. Как изменить это?
Хостинг `zzz.com.ua`

**P.S.** По данному вопросу искал ответы, но решения не нашёл, к сожалению.

Comment: приложите содержание `.htaccess`

Comment: @tCode `ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php`

Comment: а попробуйте указать полный путь, т.е. `ErrorDocument 404 http://site.com/errors/404.php`

Comment: @tCode, всё равно на стандартную страницу выводит. Где-то писали, что в настройках хостинга (панель управления) можно поменять, только я ничего такого не нашёл. Возможно, потому что бесплатный хостинг, не знаю даже.

Comment: скорее всего именно из-за того, что хостинг бесплатный...

Comment: @tCode, то есть обычно на платном хостинге просто файлик в корень кидаю, и всё работает, как часы?

Comment: не могу сказать, т.к. самому не приходилось пользоваться этой директивой, обычно это разруливается на уровне движка